# Getting an average of doubles from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm creating a program that stores doubles in an array and then stores each array in an ArrayList then calculates the average from that ArrayList, but I keep getting a "possible lossy conversion from double to int." in line 5.

I'm new to java so I might be overseeing a simple fix.

```
public static double calculateAll(List<double[]> allNumbers) {  
    double average = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < allNumbers.size(); i++) {
        total += allNumbers.get(i);
    }
    average = total/allNumbers.size();
        return average;
}
```

Comment: `for(double i = 0.0` --> change it to `for(int i = 0`

Comment: Why do you use a double for the variable i? It's an index in a list. Indices in a list are integers, not doubles.

Comment: @vinS might aswell use a foreach whole ur at it

Comment: `List<double[]>` are you SURE you wanted this? This is creating a Collection that holds double arrays.

Comment: `allNumbers.get(i)` return an array. `total += allNumbers.get(i);` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SamzSakerz I'm pretty sure... Like I said I'm new so I might be going at it the wrong way. I'm trying to get the average of all of the list's doubles and calculate the average.

Comment: @achAmháin I tied correcting it but I now get incompatible types between 'total' and 'allNumbers'. "First type: double second type double[]"

Comment: Look at my answer, You can do it in 1 line via java 8.

Comment: @bloocool for that latest issue, just replace `average = total/allNumbers.size();` by `average = total/(allNumbers.size());` and it should work.

Comment: @AnisR. The OP is overcomplicating this, I have already provided an answer with streams that can do this in 1 line.

Comment: @SamzSakerz good answer, much simpler indeed, but I was just replying to bloocool's last comment.

Comment: @SamzSakerz Oh man, thanks! I'll give this a shot. I needed to refresh the page.
Yeah, like I said, "I'm new to java so I might be overseeing a simple fix."
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @bloocool You can either use to `foreach` loop or the `stream` How ever stream requires java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking in the question, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public static double calculateAll(List<Double> allNumbers) {
    double average;
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Double allNumber : allNumbers) {
        total += allNumber;
    }
    average = total / allNumbers.size();
    return average;
}
```

You were storing an Array Inside a Collection. So I have changed that to `Double` note that `double` is native while `Double` isn't. You can't have `double` inside a Collection. and then I have converted the `for` loop into a `foreach` loop

Here is how you can call this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
    doubles.add(0.1);
    doubles.add(4.1);
    double wat = calculateAll(doubles);
    System.out.println(wat);
}
```

So lets take a note of all the changes we have done.

`List<double[]>` has been replaced with `List<Double>`.

`List` now holds items of instance `Double`

`for(int i = 0; i < allNumbers.size(); i++)` was changed to `for (Double allNumber : allNumbers)` this is just a basic for-each loop.

Honestly I would just use java 8 for this, We can do this in 1 line!

```
public static double calculateAll(List<Double> allNumbers) {
    return allNumbers.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e / allNumbers.size()).sum();
}
```